# Как в одном запросе заполнить поля и user_id и anime_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модели:
**Аниме** у каждого аниме есть много комментариев (**связь**)
**Комментарии** принадлежат аниме и пользователям (**связь**)
**Пользователь** (от гема Devise) у пользователя есть много комментариев (**связь**)

Я вношу в базу комментарии и новость к которой он относится.

```
def create
        @anime = Anime.friendly.find(params[:anime_id])
        @comment = @anime.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit(:comtxt))
        redirect_to anime_path(@anime)
    end
```

После того, как добавляется комментарий, мы там редиректимся на ту страницу, на которой были.
Проверил. Всё нормально. Таблица стала вот такой:

```
+----+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | user_id | anime_id | comtxt             | created_at              | updated_at              |
+----+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  |         |          | щшрлодрлд          | 2016-02-21 18:36:39 UTC | 2016-02-21 18:36:39 UTC |
| 2  |         | 2        | ghjghj             | 2016-02-21 19:40:15 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:40:15 UTC |
| 3  |         | 2        | ghjghjkl;          | 2016-02-21 19:41:36 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:41:36 UTC |
| 4  |         | 2        | ghjghjkl;          | 2016-02-21 19:41:36 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:41:36 UTC |
| 5  |         | 2        | с пользователеморл | 2016-02-21 19:46:27 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:46:27 UTC |
| 6  |         | 2        | с пользователеморл | 2016-02-21 19:46:27 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:46:27 UTC |
| 7  |         | 1        | орлрод             | 2016-02-21 19:49:25 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:49:25 UTC |
| 8  |         | 1        | орлрод             | 2016-02-21 19:49:25 UTC | 2016-02-21 19:49:25 UTC |
| 9  |         | 3        | ytutyuytu          | 2016-02-21 20:06:23 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:06:23 UTC |
| 10 |         | 3        | два комента        | 2016-02-21 20:18:14 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:18:14 UTC |
| 11 | 1       |          | два комента        | 2016-02-21 20:18:14 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:18:14 UTC |
| 12 |         | 3        | gfhfghhjhk         | 2016-02-21 20:20:00 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:20:00 UTC |
| 13 | 1       |          | gfhfghhjhk         | 2016-02-21 20:20:00 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:20:00 UTC |
| 14 |         | 3        | jki                | 2016-02-21 20:21:01 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:21:01 UTC |
| 15 |         | 3        | jkijhkhjk          | 2016-02-21 20:21:10 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:21:10 UTC |
| 16 |         | 3        | hgjjkjh            | 2016-02-21 20:22:38 UTC | 2016-02-21 20:22:38 UTC |
+----+---------+----------+--------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

А как теперь добавить `ID` пользователя к этому комментарию?

Я его нахожу так:

```
 @user = User.find(current_user)
```

А как его вместе сразу за 1 запрос вогнать и user_id и Anime_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Можно ещё веселее:

```
@anime.comments.merge(
  @user.comments
).create!(...)
```

При условии, что у `User` `has_many :comments`.

В сущности, метод берёт накладываемые первым скоупом параметры и накладывает поверх них параметры из другого скоупа. Поскольку `@anime.comments` накладывает `{anime_id: N}`, а `@user.comments` накладывает `{user_id: M}`, то их смесь будет `{anime_id: N, user_id: M}`.

**Метод в чём-то аналогичен `Hash#merge`.** Особенно той деталью, что если требования двух скоупов конфликтуют, то в результате будет **последний примешанный**. Пример:

```
@anime1.comments.merge(@anime2.comments).to_sql == @anime2.comments.to_sql
```

Так можно смешивать не только ассоциации, но и скоупы, причём при использовании `joins` можно смешивать скоупы **на разных моделях**, что особенно убойно. К примеру, вот гипотетический пример запроса всех комментариев, авторы которых админы:

```
Comment.joins(:user).merge(
  User.where(admin: true)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Решилось с помощью:

```
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
```